# Can you render a (old) asp.net usercontrol in a asp.net mvc 3 website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I was wondering if there is a way to render (non mvc) asp.net usercontrols in a asp.net mvc website.

I have googled it and i am experimenting with it, but haven't found a clear answer (yet).

Any1 has a clear answer on this?

Comment: have you read this series? http://hugoware.net/blog/using-webcontrols-in-asp-net-mvc-views-part-1

Comment: No worries, I won't promote the comment to an answer though as it is lazy and someone might have a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render them but if they rely on viewstate and postback, they won't work.

Comment: yep, you can fake it, but it is rather dirty work. Thx for the help