# I want to combine the good features of both MVC and Web Forms. Can I do that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

Initially, I want to use dynamic data and binding with validation with web forms and combine it with MVC. Is it possible to combine both of them on a single web application?

One important thing also is I want to use the built-in role based memberships in ASP.NET Web Forms.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In a project I did use both and it works fine. In my case, I added web forms into my MVC application, I haven't tried the other way round but I guess it is not possible building MVC application on an ASP.net website/application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in membership system from asp. It is available. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx)

The dynamic binding is a other problem since you send objects to a view. That view has to deal with the objects in his own way.

To reuse webform controls:
There has been some research to it but it is difficult to do.
And even then it is not always the way you want it.

See my question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191700/can-you-render-a-old-asp-net-usercontrol-in-a-asp-net-mvc-3-website)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to combine Dynamic Data with ASP.NET MVC. You can use the scaffolding in MVC to get you started. The membership is available in MVC.

Comment: are you referring to the helper DisplayForModel as the scaffolding for MVC?

Comment: This is probably what RickAndMSFT is referring to: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/